# returning a function in a nested function (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, function, return

hopefully someone will be able to help me solve this issue that I'm dealing with.
I am trying to return a function inside a function but my code seems not to work... using Javascript.
Here is my code :

```
function chosenPiece() {
  if (isWhite) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      whitePiecesList[i].addEventListener("click", function findPositionOnBoard(event) {
        for (let i = 0; i < boardCellsList.length; i++) {
          if (boardCellsList[i].firstElementChild === event.target) {
            let position = i;
            return position;
          }
        }
      });
    }
  } else {
    for (let i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
      blackPiecesList[i].addEventListener("click", function findPositionOnBoard(event) {
        for (let i = 0; i < boardCellsList.length; i++) {
          if (boardCellsList[i].firstElementChild === event.target) {
            let position = i;
            return position;
          }
        }
      });
    }
  }
  return findPositionOnBoard();
}
```

Can someone identify the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Using `return` inside envent listeners doesn't make sense. That value can't be used.

Comment: "*my code seems not to work*" what's the problem? Do you get an error? Do you get the wrong output? What's the expected input and output for this?

Comment: Super nitpicky.  Why do you need a `position` variable?  Just return `i`

Comment: You can return a reference to a function by omitting the parentheses in the return statement. Adding parentheses actually executes the function and returns the function's return value

Comment: where do you get `boardCellsList` from?

Comment: The scope of the name in a named function expression is just the body of the function. So you can't refer to `findPositionOnBoard` outside those functions. You need to declare the name in the `chosenPiece` function body, then assign it before returning it.

Comment: The `chosenPiece` function is running now. It can't return a value *after* a button is clicked because that won't happen until the future.

Comment: But it's not clear why you would want to return the function that's being used as an event listener in the first place. Do you need it so you can call `removeEventListener()` later?